# Do 8d nails come in different lengths?

Tags: framing, fastener, nails, framing-fasteners

From what I can tell, 8 Penny nails are 2 1/2" long. [Charts on the internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=8d%2016d%20nail%20size&sxsrf=ALeKk03XNCxk_N4e9DkQ3kSqJBUfEgl6JA:1588010401565&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjCv4nfl4npAhVDRa0KHUSEBUAQ_AUoA3oECA4QBQ&biw=1344&bih=720#imgrc=P-233VA-aTuwNM) back this up.

But I was looking at the nailing guide for [this hurricane tie](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Simpson-Strong-Tie-H1-18-Gauge-ZMAX-Galvanized-Hurricane-Tie-H1Z/100374935) on homedepot.com and it specifies two different 8d nail lengths.

[image]

A search on Home Depot does not come up with any 1.5" 8d nails. What's going on here?

Comment: Those are "joist hanger nails" - same diameter for shear strength, but shorter than standard so you don't have an extra inch trying to come out the other side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard 8d nails are 2.5" long.  Anything else is going to be some sort of special purpose nail such as these:

[8d 1.5" nails](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Simpson-Strong-Tie-Strong-Drive-8d-x-1-1-2-in-SCN-Smooth-Shank-Connector-Nail-5-lb-N8D5HDG-R/206101771)